# Postman - Caracteres escape respuesta XML

Tags: xml, post, utf-8, postman, soapui

Acabo de empezar a hacer pruebas de API con Postman, por lo que tampoco tengo mucha experiencia, y me está pasando algo que me está volviendo loca y no sé cómo solucionar.

Estoy intentando hacer una request de tipo POST con un XML de entrada.
La request se envía, y se recibe correctamente la respuesta, sin embargo esta respuesta me devuelve caracteres de escape que no sé cómo omitir.
Esta respuesta se visualiza así tanto en Pretty format como en Raw. He probado toqueteando los headers para que incluyesen utf-8, sin ningún éxito.

La request es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sisnet.framework.webservices.jaxws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:execute>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>LOGIN</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>
            <![CDATA[
               <ROOT>
                  <COMANDO>
                     <CODIGO>LOGIN</CODIGO>
                     <VERSION>1</VERSION>
                     <TIPODUSO>VOID</TIPODUSO>
                  </COMANDO>
                  <ENTRADA>
                     <USUARIO>{{user}}</USUARIO>
                     <CONTRASEÑA>{{pass}}</CONTRASEÑA>
                     <CODIMEDI>{{codMediator}}</CODIMEDI>
                     <PROVACCE>{{accessProv}}</PROVACCE>
                  </ENTRADA>
               </ROOT>
            ]]>
         </arg1>
      </urn:execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Añadir que también he probado sacando el CDATA e incluyendo los caracteres de escape correspondientes (no tiene mucho sentido porque es lo mismo, pero lo he probado). Mismo resultado.

La respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:executeResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:sisnet.framework.webservices.jaxws">
            <return>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
&lt;ROOT>
&lt;RETORNO>
&lt;CODIGO>0&lt;/CODIGO>
&lt;DESCRIPCION>Comando invocado correctamente.&lt;/DESCRIPCION>
&lt;EXCEPCION>&lt;/EXCEPCION>
&lt;COMENTARIO>&lt;/COMENTARIO>
&lt;AVISOS>
&lt;/AVISOS>

&lt;/RETORNO>
&lt;RESPUESTA>
&lt;IDSESION>IDSESIONIDSESIONIDSESIONIDSESIONIDSESION&lt;/IDSESION>

&lt;/RESPUESTA>
&lt;/ROOT></return>
        </ns2:executeResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Edito para añadir el endpoint y el contenido del WSDL:

```
<definitions
    xmlns:tns="urn:sisnet.framework.webservices.jaxws"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:sisnet.framework.webservices.jaxws" name="WSSISNetService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="urn:sisnet.framework.webservices.jaxws" schemaLocation="http://lalalallaalalalala/SisnetINT/WSSISNet?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="execute">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:execute"/>
    </message>
    <message name="executeResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:executeResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="WSSISNet">
        <operation name="execute">
            <input message="tns:execute"/>
            <output message="tns:executeResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="WSSISNetPortBinding" type="tns:WSSISNet">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="execute">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WSSISNetService">
        <port name="WSSISNetPort" binding="tns:WSSISNetPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://lalallalallalala/SisnetINT/WSSISNet"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Cabe destacar que esta misma request exactamente sí que devuelve el resultado esperado si la ejecuto en SoapUI.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Parece que no estás indicando XML, y te está devolviendo HTML. [Revisa las indicaciones aquí](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/making-soap-requests/) donde se explica paso a paso cómo hacer una petición Soap desde Postman.

Comment: Gracias por responder.
Tengo seteado XML tanto en la request como en la respuesta. Sigue devolviendo caracteres rarunos :(

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta y poner el código de servidor que atiende la petición y devuelve la respuesta?

Comment: Uhm creo que no entiendo tu pregunta, perdona
Te refieres a la request URL? Al código que me devuelve la respuesta?
Sorry estoy muy verde todavía en esto.

Comment: La petición es enviada a alguna parte del servidor, que la recibe, procesa los datos y te devuelve una respuesta que debería ser un XML, pero al parecer lo que te está devolviendo es HTML, entonces me refiero a que muestres el archivo de servidor al que mandas los datos desde Postman. En *endpoint*  o como se llame. No uso Postman, pero supongo que hay una parte donde pones la URL a la que diriges la petición y en esa URL hay un archivo o un controlador o algo al que se dirige la petición.

Comment: Vale sí, no te había entendido.
El endpoint no es más que un WSDL, edito y enchufo el código arriba.

Comment: ¿Eso es lo que hay en la URL que pones en PostMan? ¿Es la URL correcta, seguro?

Comment: Segurísimo.

No pongo la url entera porque daría igual, hay que estar conectado a una VPN para poder acceder, ese es el contenido del WSDL tal cual.

Comment: ¿Seguiste los pasos indicados en mi primer comentario para mandar la petición? Si no estás enviando datos en el body prueba con una petición del tipo `GET` en vez de `POST`.

Comment: He seguido todos los pasos, no me estoy dejando nada de los tutoriales básicos, los he mirado 30 veces jejeeje

No puede ser tipo GET porque sí que estoy enviando contenido en el body, además envío y recibo correctamente la respuesta, solo que en un formato equivocado.

Comment: Pues no sé que decirte. Por ejemplo esa `Ñ` en la palabra `CONTRASEÑA` y los caracteres acentuados o especiales suelen fastidiarlo todo si no trabajas bien la condificación en la petición y en la respuesta. En algunos casos parece que ha funcionado evitando usar `CDATA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré respuesta a la pregunta, me ayudaron en la comunidad de Postman para lo que buscaba.
Dejo el enlace por si a alguien más le sirve: [Solución](https://community.postman.com/t/xml-response-escape-characters/14450)

Comment: Deberías agregar aqui la solución amig@ por favor